# How to join table with prefix column to another two table in PHP MySQL or Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Is this possible to `join table` with prefic column to another two `table` in `MySQL`
**For Example**
 First `Customer` **table** has column `ID` `Name` and
Second `Supplier` **table** has column `ID` `Name` and 
Third `Purchase` **table** has column `ID` `Product` `Party`
I want  join these three table `Purchase` **table** column `Party` to both **table** `Customer` and `Supplier` column `ID`
[image]
Here `cus_` mean `ID` form `Customer` table and
Here `sup_` mean `ID` form `Supplier` table
**Can any one solve this joining? without prefix** `Customer` **or** `Supplier` **table** `PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join with customer table:

```
select * from purchase_table pt inner join Customer c on 
select replace(pt.party,'cus_','')=c.id and pt.party like 'cus_%'
```

To join with supplier table:

```
select * from purchase_table pt inner join Supplier s on 
select replace(pt.party,'sup_','')=s.id and pt.party like 'sup_%'
```